# Sumar columna cantidad de un dato repetido

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Uso Visual Basic .NET y MariaDB.

Quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer para que a la hora de insertar un dato a la base de datos, si está repetido, solo sume la cantidad y si no existe ningún registro parecido que haga uno nuevo.

Soy prácticamente nuevo y no sé mucho. Cualquier ayuda me serviría.

Éste es el código que usé para agregar datos. ¿Cómo podría modificarlo?

```
Try
    CONN = New MySqlConnection(STR)
    CONN.Open()

    If MessageBox.Show("Esta seguro que desea guardar los datos escritos? ", "GUARDAR", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

        Dim query As String = "insert into entradas (NO_DE_PARTE, CANTIDAD_INGRESADA, DESCRIPCION, MARCA, TIPO_DE_PIEZA, PROYECTO, FECHA_DE_INGRESO) values 
                            (@NO_DE_PARTE, @CANTIDAD_INGRESADA, @DESCRIPCION, @MARCA, @TIPO_DE_PIEZA, @PROYECTO, @FECHA_DE_INGRESO)"

        CMD = New MySqlCommand(query, CONN)
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@NO_DE_PARTE", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@CANTIDAD_INGRESADA", MySqlDbType.Decimal, 18.0)
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@DESCRIPCION", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@MARCA", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@TIPO_DE_PIEZA", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@PROYECTO", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHA_DE_INGRESO", Date.Today.Date)

        CMD.Parameters("@NO_DE_PARTE").Value = Me.TXT_NO_PART.Text.ToUpper.ToString
        CMD.Parameters("@CANTIDAD_INGRESADA").Value = Me.TXT_C_INGRES.Text.ToString
        CMD.Parameters("@DESCRIPCION").Value = Me.DES_TXT.Text.ToUpper.ToString
        CMD.Parameters("@MARCA").Value = Me.TXT_MARC.Text.ToUpper.ToString
        CMD.Parameters("@TIPO_DE_PIEZA").Value = Me.TXT_TIPO_PIEZA.Text.ToUpper.ToString
        CMD.Parameters("@PROYECTO").Value = Me.TXT_PROYECT.Text.ToUpper.ToString
        CMD.Parameters("@FECHA_DE_INGRESO").Value = Me.FECHA_DATE.Value


        CMD.Connection = CONN
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MessageBox.Show("Los datos se registraron correctamente", "Nuevo Dato", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    End If
    CONN.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString)
Finally
    CONN.Close()

End Try
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A tu pregunta le faltaría la consulta SQL del INSERT para poder aplicarla con la solución que te he propuesto.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la cláusula [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) para que haga el trabajo.

Basta con hacer clave única el campo común para tus registros y actualizar el campo de cantidad en caso de que insertes una clave ya existente.

Un ejemplo sería:

```
INSERT INTO tabla
  (clave, cantidad)
VALUES
  (1, 5)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  cantidad = cantidad + VALUES(cantidad)
```

Comment: Buenos días, como podría escribirlo para vb net es que no es la misma sintaxys, abajo deje mi codigo de vb net para agregar datos

Comment: Hola @AntonioGuzman . Voy a editar tu pregunta para agregar lo que has añadido como respuesta. Recuerda que debes usar el botón "editar" que hay bajo ella para agregar nueva información. Cuando tenga un hueco te respondo.